# The gapi.client is not created after loading the Googe API correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the YouTube API to create a small webapp. However, it seems like the gapi.client object is not being created. The code runs on the Google API console but not locally.

I have loaded the JS scripts as follows:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

In the app.js the loadClient function is as follows:

```
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
```

An error shows up when the below line is executed:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
```

The error ---> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setApiKey' of undefined at loadClient (app.js:7)

I'd like to understand why this is happening and how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing those `type` attributes on your `<script>` tags

Comment: Where and how are you calling `loadClient()`? You should have `gapi.load('client', someFunction)` somewhere, do you?

Comment: I'm calling it  before I call any other function.
`gapi.load("client");`
`loadClient();`
 `execute();`

Comment: That's not how you should use `gapi.load()`. You need to pass it a callback function which it executes when the library has been loaded, eg `gapi.load('client', loadClient)`

Comment: Great! I was able to make it work. Thank you.